# Extend Width of Navbar-Right in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

I'm having problems extending the navbar-right in Bootstrap. I need it to fit all the elements in it. Here is what's going on:

[image]

I can't get the profile image and the username to display separately. I've tried "clear: both" and the normal stuff. When I extend the size of the UL, it breaks the parent DIV. When I try to extend the size of the LI, it doesn't do anything. Here is my code:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"> <span class="site-title">Privy Personal</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Files</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Sharing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Recent</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Deleted</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Search.svg"> </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Notification.svg"> </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="username">Tony Stark</span><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" class="profile"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </nav> <!-- End Fixed Nav -->
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Add `<div class="container-fluid">` after `<nav>` and adjust the name and picture alignment with margin.

Try this

check demo [**here**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/LRQXdX?editors=1100)

HTML:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="site-title">Privy Personal</span></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Files</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Sharing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Recent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deleted</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="username">Tony Stark</span><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" class="profile img-circle"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- End Fixed Nav -->
```

CSS:

```
.username {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.profile {
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

I hope it helps you :)